# Proof Bounded Implies a Limit Exists

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble with the Riemann Removable Singularities Theorem, namely I can't see how to show that a (mero?)morhpic function being bounded in a neighborhood of a singularity implies that the limit as you approach the point exists. The first counterexample that came to mind is something like $\sin(1/x)$ although I understand that $\sin(1/z)$ doesn't exhibit the same periodic behavior outside of the real line. Moreover, I understand that a function can't be doubly periodic without being constant- so while I can't think of any counterexamples (indeed there aren't any) I still don't know how to prove the statement.

Comment: I suppose I could work with the fact that the maximum must occur on the boundary. Then if there was any periodicity I could just shrink the radius until that was the maximum/minimum. If it wasn't on the boundary it would be constant. I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This standard proof is from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, Thm.10.20. If the function$f(z)$ has its isolated singularity at $a$, define $h(a)=0$ and $= (z-a)^2f(z)$ elsewhere on the domain of $f$. Boundedness shows that $h'(a)=0$. Since $h$ is clearly holomorphic on the domain of $f$, it has a power series expansion in $z-a$. Extend $f$ to a holomorphic function by defining $f(a)= c_2$ where $c_2$ is the coefficient of $(z-a)^2$ in the series of $h$.